# Software to make Khan Academy style video tutorials, on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, image-editor, drawing, educational

What are the options for the drawing part of training videos on Khan Academy?

I am looking for something better than [KolourPaint](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kolourpaint4/) (which is similar to mspaint on Windows), but not as complex as GIMP.

It also needs to be in the style of hand-writing and hand-drawing, so Dia is not an option.

The [list](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/department/drawing/) on Ubuntu apps does not look very promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Xournal](http://xournal.sourceforge.net/) is the best tool I found to write with a digital pen. It makes for a terrible image editor, but being able to move the traces that you've written/drawn around is a great feature. I recommend binding the lazo tool to the side button in your pen. Also, by default it shows very ugly horizontal lines, notebook style. You can change that to a plain black background, khan academy style.

You can also annotate pdf's with it. I don't remember if it has a save to image feature, but I usually take an area screenshot of the part I want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found it more like what I am looking for, (which is something other than an image editor)

Answer (score 3):

Krita is quite a nice alternative to GIMP, and a bit simpler. Here's a link: https://www.calligra.org/krita/

Here's some of the features:

- An adaptive multi-modal interface which works on the desktop and touchscreens
- A large set of default brushes
- Customizable brush presets
- Multiple brush engines, supports pressure sensitivity, tilt and other features of graphics tablets
- Wrap around mode canvas for creating and visualizing seamlessly tiled textures
- OpenGL powered canvas with high-bit-depth monitor support
- Filters with real-time preview
- A layer engine that allows deeply nested and grouped layers
- Vector, clone, external-file and dynamic filter-effect layers
- Supports a wide range of file formats and color models

It's easy to install on ubuntu: `sudo aptitude install krita`
And on Fedora: `sudo dnf install krita`
And on Arch: `pacman -S krita`

Comment: I change the accepted answer to Xournal. See the comment in there

Answer (score 1):

You Should Try My Paint. It is GNU GPL licensed FLOSS software and is a great tool for painting. But it suits your needs perfectly.

Here are a few features you will find Great:-

[image]

- Loads of Brushes Are Already installed!!

[image]

- A huge selection of backgrounds to suite Your needs. **It has some just like Xournal**

[image]

- Smooth Brush Strokes (Unfortunately Xournal's aren't that smooth )

[image]

- Support For layers

[image]

- Unlimited canvas With Scrolling

**NOTE**

Since Krita has these and a little more features it is better if and only if you use KDE. If not My paint is super quick for your needs And allows custom brushes.

The theme appears Black as I use Vertex-Dark gtk theme

Comment: Its made for Graphic Tablets But can be used with mouse