# Video from Images Sounds and other videos

Tags: linux, video-editing

I liked Windows Movie Maker on Windows before I installed Linux.
I want a software which can combine Videos images and music(mp3) and apply transitions in it. It may not have the fancy effects of the Movie Maker But it should have the Transitions. Also It is better if it is GUI and has a timeline Editing.
Recommended FLOSS.

Comment: Related and having answers: [Open source video editing software for linux?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/14656/185) (what's wrong with that? Seems almost the same question to me) / [Software to make Khan Academy style video tutorials, on Ubuntu](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/18650/185)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at [Pitivi](http://pitivi.org/):

- You can mix in sound tracks
- GUI based
- Linux
- Open Source
- Over 70 transitions.

[image: ScreenShot]